# ImageMagick: make changes with stack B1B2B3 before composite with image A

Tags: shell, imagemagick

I use the following string to composite each of B images with A:

```
convert A null: B*.png -gravity center -layers composite AB%d.png
```

The result is AB1, AB2 and AB3 and it's ok.

The next case is to make some changes with B stack, before it's composed with A. EG: -flop, -level, etc. It's also important to keep "AB%d.png" naming pattern.

How the command line should looks to do this preliminary changes with B stack and keep naming patten?

Comment: Do you mean `convert A null: \( B*.png -flop -level ... \) ...`?

Comment: yes, exactly. And it works! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, **ImageMagick** commands have *"settings"* and *"operators"* and things that create canvases.

*"Settings"* are things like the background colour, the fill colour, the gravity and these settings stay set from the point you write them on the command line till the end and apply to everything that follows to the right.

*"Operators"*, like `-crop` and `-append` actually change some aspect of an image and apply to everything currently in the stack of images - i.e. everything to the left of where they occur.

Things that create their own canvas to draw on can be recognised because they generally have a colon in them, so `xc:`, `gradient:` and `label:` all create canvas.

If you want to stop operators applying to too much stuff to their left, you have a couple of ways of doing that. Either create the stuff you want to manipulate first and manipulate it, then add the other stuff afterwards:

```
convert ChangeMe.png AndMe.png -crop XYZ -level XYZ LeaveMeUnchanged.png -composite ...
```

and possibly use `+swap` afterwards to re-order.

Or, use parentheses so that operators only apply to a limited subset of the stack:

```
convert LeaveMeUnchanged.png \( ChangeMe.png AndMe.png -crop \) ...
```

---

So, in answer to your specific question:

```
convert A null: \( B*.png -flop -level ... \) ...
```